# Does TypeORM support automatically cascade deletion?

Tags: nestjs, one-to-many, typeorm

This is not a specific coding question - more of a general question. I can't find an answer one-way or the other in the documentation.

Let's say we have an entity called **Invoice** that contains many **LineItem** entities, and I set this up using `ManyToOne()` and `OneToMany()` as the documentation describes. Also, we make sure to include `cascade: true` in the `OneToMany()` decorator options.

Now, let's create an Invoice object with 2 LineItems. If I save this Invoice, TypeORM correctly cascades and saves these to the database automatically - everything is working great; I only need 1 line of code to save 3 rows to the database.

Now, let's suppose I remove one of those LineItems from the array and re-save the Invoice. In this situation, TypeORM is throwing an error that looks like:

```
QueryFailedError: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'invoice_line_item_id' cannot be null
```

This error is clear to me: I'm assuming that TypeORM understands that this LineItem is no longer associated to an Invoice, but instead of deleting the LineItem (which is what I want TypeORM to do), it's trying to update the row and set the foreign key `invoice_line_item_id` to `null` instead. Naturally, this foreign key is not nullable, so mysql complains.

How do I tell TypeORM to delete this row instead? Do I have to manually remove the children using `repository.remove()`? Do I need remove `isNullable: false`? (Not ideal)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From `RelationOptions.d.ts` in TypeORM:

> - Sets cascades options for the given relation.
> - If set to true then it means that related object can be allowed to be inserted or updated in the database.

So, I believe you could add an additional option to your decorators like `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` and it would fix your issue. For example:

```
@ManyToOne(data => data, { cascade: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's one of the first things I tried - it doesn't really seem to do anything as the same error message occurs. There's actually a github fix for this issue but it's still awaiting review by one of their team members :(

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/6704

I really hope they can address this. Writing this deletion code manually in dozens of spots is going to be a pain considering how deep these delete decisions are in my entity graphs